# Instead of Role ID, Role Name Discord.js

Tags: discord.js, names

I want to count the Members with a specific Role in two different Discords. I tried to make it work with the Role Name instead of Role ID. Unfortunately it's not working as it should.

````
else if(parts[0] == 't!Verified') {
    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Verified");
    let membersWithRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get(role.name);
    message.channel.send(`There are ${membersWithRole.members.size} Verified Members on this Discord`)```
````

The Error Code that is happening is:

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.find( r => { r.name == "role_name"});
```

For the second part of your question you may not find a role in every guild with the same ID so you can use `try/catch`

```js
try {
message.guild.roles.cache.find( r => { r.name == "role_name"});
} catch(e) {
// Suppress the error else console.log(e) if don't want to suppress 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i know that i can't find the same ID in every guild but my problem is that my bot crashes when he can't find the specific ID and i don't want that. Do you have an Idea for that?

Comment: I literally included that in my answer, try/catch will work around that

Comment: Sorry i was lost yesterday with that catch thing. I tried to change the Role ID to the Name with you're Code. Now my problem is that i can't use the rest of the Code properly. I changed it a bit but now i have the Problem that the last part isn't working.

My new Code right now is: 

`else if(parts[0] == 't!verified') {
        let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Verified");
        let membersWithRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get(role.name);
        message.channel.send(`There are ${membersWithRole.size} verified Members on this Server`)`

Comment: Could you send me the error you're facing

Comment: My Error Code is: 

message.channel.send(`There are ${membersWithRole.size} Verified Members on this Server`)
                                                      
TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined

Comment: For that you need to replace it to `${membersWithRole.members.size}`

Comment: I tried that now my Error Code is: 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined

Comment: Could you try adding await to your membersWithRole? Like ```await message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == "Verified")``` also make sure you don't have any special characters in the role name and it's Verified without any emojis or font changes.

Comment: Could you try adding await to your membersWithRole? Like ```await message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == "Verified")``` also make sure you don't have any special characters in the role name and it's Verified without any emojis or font changes.

Comment: Same Error Code with the await

Comment: Please check the name of the role then

Comment: I checked the name of the Role. No Emojis in the Role or anything. I don't unterstand why members are not defined.